# Handle json jquery ajax response 2 arrays

Tags: php, ajax, json

I am not that good at ajax, javascript and so on.

I echoed from my PHP file 2 JSON arrays:

```
{key":"R\/EPspiig3jNffjjE6YWTsB+rsdlCjqnm1LExC\/vJXE=","nonce":"1aab51c5d8b23b7c110ae3f2a2d440bf0797750c85bd1602e8d57c357f34dab9"}
```

and

```
{"error":1,"message":"\u05d4\u05d0\u05d9\u05de\u05d9\u05d9\u05dc \u05e9\u05d4\u05d6\u05e0\u05ea \u05e9\u05d2\u05d5\u05d9 \u05d0\u05d5 \u05dc\u05d0 \u05ea\u05e7\u05d9\u05df \u05e0\u05e1\u05d4 \u05e9\u05d5\u05d1 ,\u05d0\u05e0\u05d0 \u05d4\u05db\u05e0\u05e1 \u05e1\u05d9\u05e1\u05de\u05d0"}
```

in my ajax i have this :

success: function(data)
      {

```
           obj = JSON && JSON.parse(data) || $.parseJSON(data);

           if(data[0].login == true) 
            {  
                window.location = "index.php";

            }
            else
              {
             $("#siimage").trigger("click");
             $("form input:submit").effect("shake", {times:2}, 100);
             $("#errorMessage").html(data[0].message); 
             $("#nonce").val(data[1].nonce);
             $("#key").val(data[1].key);
              }




         if(data.cblocked == true)
         {
         $("#email").prop('disabled', true);
         $("#password").prop('disabled', true);
         $('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled','disabled');
         document.getElementById("Submit").value = 'נעול';

         }
          if(data.csrf == true)
         {
         $("#email").prop('disabled', true);
         $("#password").prop('disabled', true);
         $('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled','disabled');
         document.getElementById("Submit").value = 'נעול';

         }
```

this the problem :

```
$("#nonce").val(data[1].nonce);
             $("#key").val(data[1].key);
```

how i using that ,because i have 2 arrays anyway i using parse and handle 2 arrays this way ? like data[0] = array 1 and data[1] = array 2 ?

Answer (score 0):

First, check the `.responseText` property of your Ajax request object (the `HttpRequestObject`) like this:

```
alert(request.responseText)
```

If that looks right, you've got two arrays sort of mashed together.  You need to split them up using `.split()` and some character pattern (I used `:::` for example):

```
twoarrays = request.responseText.split(":::");
```

Now, you've got two strings in JSON format at addresses `[0]` and `[1]` in `twoarrays`.  Use `.parse()` to convert each one back into an array.

If you don't understand what I'm talking about, it's time for you to do some research.  It's not tricky stuff, you'll just have to spend some time getting it in your head.

---

*(old answer)*

If you mean the *Javascript* side, then

```
yourstring.parse()
```

should work fine ([Parse JSON in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/how-to-parse-json-in-javascript)).

You may need to `.split()` the response using a newline or something:

```
twoarrays = request.responseText.split("\n");
array1 = twoarrays[0].parse();
array2 = twoarrays[1].parse();
```

If you mean the *PHP* side, then you can use `json_decode($yourstring, true)` which [parses the JSON](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) into an associative array (the one with names instead of numbers for addresses).

Just FYI, `json_encode($yourarray)` will do the opposite.

Comment: thanks for ur help but not to fast i am newbie :P , i have this success: function(data)
      {  
can u ex how i do it on the data , sry i am very very newbie and learning things out..

Comment: No worries. First, are you talking about PHP or Javascript?  Looks like Javascript?  Then, don't panic, and try what I said: `.parse()`.

Comment: yea javascript , i need to handle 2 arrays , 1 is error array and the other is just a hashed keys , please look my question i edited.

Comment: If there's no error, that means you're doing something right.  Just a minute I'll edit my answer.

Comment: look my edited question , i have 2 json arrays , i need 1 to echo php error and the other just val hashed keys , as far i have the good json response but i dont know how to parse it so its both work

Comment: Wow now you've changed your question again.  Sorry, I'm tired of helping now.  Next time please make a clear, well formatted request that is easy for people to understand.  Incidentally, it looks like there's a lot of code in your javascript that you don't understand.  Start there.

Comment: sry, i have bad english :( .. i know everything i just dont know how to handle 2 json arrays that come from my php..

Comment: Your English is OK.  Your Javascript needs some work.  Your code is too complicated for you to handle, I think.  Start with something more basic.

Comment: i made that javascript alone... till now i used just 1 array that handle login form errors , but now i using 2 arrays so i dont know how to use with 2 arrays , so 1 will echo the errors like before and the 2 other will val hashed keys can u still help me to fix it so it will work with 2 arrays ? :\